# Boomi NetSuite Upsert Response - Get External IDs of Upserted Records

Tags: integration, netsuite, boomi

2020-07-09 EDIT: Apparently this is a defect.  I finally got them to admit that, and they have filed a fix for it.  I'll leave this open until the issue is completely resolved, though.

---

I'm trying to clean up a Boomi integration that has three branches just to upsert records and then get the external ID from the NetSuite response.  Every successful NetSuite upsert response has the external ID of the record that was sent, but Boomi does not have seem to be able to use the actual NetSuite response.

**Example NetSuite response:**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Header>
    <platformMsgs:documentInfo xmlns:platformMsgs="urn:messages_2019_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
        <platformMsgs:nsId>##############################</platformMsgs:nsId>
    </platformMsgs:documentInfo>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
    <upsertListResponse xmlns="urn:messages_2019_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
        <writeResponseList>
            <platformCore:status isSuccess="true" xmlns:platformCore="urn:core_2019_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com"/>
            <writeResponse>
                <platformCore:status isSuccess="true" xmlns:platformCore="urn:core_2019_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
                    <platformCore:statusDetail>
                        <platformCore:afterSubmitFailed>false</platformCore:afterSubmitFailed>
                    </platformCore:statusDetail>
                </platformCore:status>
                <baseRef xsi:type="platformCore:CustomRecordRef" typeId="144" externalId="339487-2__RcvdType__38660884__6" internalId="4341574" xmlns:platformCore="urn:core_2019_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com"/>
            </writeResponse>
            <writeResponse>
                <platformCore:status isSuccess="true" xmlns:platformCore="urn:core_2019_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
                    <platformCore:statusDetail>
                        <platformCore:afterSubmitFailed>false</platformCore:afterSubmitFailed>
                    </platformCore:statusDetail>
                </platformCore:status>
                <baseRef xsi:type="platformCore:CustomRecordRef" typeId="144" externalId="314013-12__RcvdType__38661194__6" internalId="4339771" xmlns:platformCore="urn:core_2019_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com"/>
            </writeResponse>
```

**Boomi's NetSuite respone:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Result>
  <id>#####</id>
  <success>true</success>
</Result>
```

Essentially, I just want to grab the external ID of the records from the actual NetSuite response.  I've googled around, but I'm not finding anything that works... :/

Comment: Generally if you are using external Id you are sending it as part of the UPSERT so already know it.

Comment: Brian, that's factually true.  But, you do not know the internal ID associated with that external ID.  That is why NetSuite always returns that information in every upsert response.  The problem is that now we know there was a group of records create/updated, but not what association they have to the original data set that was submitted.  Boomi is only showing the internal ID, which is useless without the external ID.